# Use Imported Classes From Parent Class In a PHP Trait Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm currently working on a PHP trait thay will help me to reuse code in some class controllers that I have using Laravel framework.

I wanted to make the trait methods as dynamic as I could but when trying to access to a class that my parent class imported, I get a `Class not found exception`.

My class controller is as follows:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\ {
    Curso,
    Leccion,
    Diapositiva,
    ImagenDiapositiva
};

use App\Traits\TestTrait;

class DiapositivasController extends Controller{
   use TestTrait;

   public function addRecord(Request $request){
      $request->class_name = 'ImagenDiapositiva';
      $this->addImage($request);
   }
}
```

My Trait:

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait TestTrait{
   public function addImage($request){
      $class_name = $request->class_name;
      $diapositiva = new $class_name;

     //extra code
   }
}
```

So my doubt is, do I have to include the model classes I want to use inside my Trait again or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `new` with a variable class name, you have to use the fully qualified class name. I'm guessing `new $class_name` is the root cause of the issue here, since `$class_name` would have to be something like: 'App\Models\ImagenDiapositiva' or whatever the full namespace is. Just have to change the call `$request->class_name = 'ImagenDiapositiva';` to reflect the full name of the class.

Comment: Okay, that seemed to have solved the problem, but why do I need the full namespace?, wouldn't it be enough that I included the full namespace in the parent class so that the Trait could use it with just the class name?

Comment: I think it enforces an explicit naming convention to avoid problems in large projects. Like the call to the `$class_name` was in the `App\Traits` namespace since that is where your call to the class is.

Comment: I see, so then I don't need to include the model class in the class controller at all, since I'm giving the full namespace anyways. Thank you very much.